# Deleted Photos to reclaim iCloud space but none reclaimed

Tags: macos, icloud, photos, storage

I have deleted photos in order to reclaim iCloud storage, followed by emptying both the **Recently Deleted** album and the macOS Trash. I also restarted my computer.

Yet my available storage hasn’t increased. What else should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any other devices using the same library?

I did similar thing last night, deleted some things from my Mac from the library (large video files, around 800mb), and then went to iPhone to check the free storage on iCloud, it wasn't changed.  And my 'Recently deleted files' was empty as well.

Then I **opened** the Photos app on iPhone, and I could notice the 'pop', the thumbnails moved, so it seems the iPhone synced that those videos are deleted, and after that when I checked the iCloud storage, free storage was increase.

So, try to open Photos on other devices to let them sync.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an iOS device, check 'iCloud>Storage>Manage Storage' in Settings to see exactly how the storage being reported is allocated; you should be able to go from there. Sometimes you have to log out then log back in to your iCloud, and even restart if it seems stuck. Hopefully it isn't worse than that. Sorry I'm brand new to macOS and am not familiar with iCloud settings on the mac, mostly iOS ...for now.